# Extract information from string to arrays

Tags: php, string, extract, explode

Hello I am not really familiar with fancy stuff that can be done with php, so i could do 200line function, when pros could do it better in few fabolus lines.
Lets say i receive string that looks like

```
[{
    "id": "9e30bb3094e00abc291016a7a597ba1840a6d6ec",
    "user_id": "adb16da39e5ecc448e2aa4aec8a34a8158fa137a",
    "document_name": "sample.pdf",
 }]
[{
    "id": "9e30bb3094e00a6c291016a7a598ba1840a6d6ec",
    "user_id": "adb16da39e5ecc448e2aa4aec8a34a8158fa137a",
    "document_name": "sample2.pdf",
 }]
```

.
.
.

Is there any neat method to get number of these "documents", their ids.
like

echo $dnumber; //5

echo $id[5]; //9e30bb3094e00a6c291016a7a598ba1840a6d6ec

Comment: is that JSON? [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering it's a JSON, you can use json_decode

```
$string = '...';
$records = json_decode($string);
echo $records[5]->id;
```

Valid JSON would be

```
[
    {
        "id": "9e30bb3094e00abc291016a7a597ba1840a6d6ec",
        "user_id": "adb16da39e5ecc448e2aa4aec8a34a8158fa137a",
        "document_name": "sample.pdf"
    },
    {
        "id": "9e30bb3094e00a6c291016a7a598ba1840a6d6ec",
        "user_id": "adb16da39e5ecc448e2aa4aec8a34a8158fa137a",
        "document_name": "sample2.pdf"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot to check what can I do with json. this solved it for me